# Cleft sentences

Tags: syntactic-analysis, emphasis

Let's assume that **John gave me a cat**. I can rephrase the fact with:

> *What John did was to give me a cat*
>   *What John did was give me a cat*
>   *What John did was, he gave me a cat*

But can I say the following phrase?

***What John did was gave me a cat***

Comment: Technically, those are ***Pseudo-Cleft*** sentences. Chuck Fillmore [explains the difference](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/fillmore.html). See [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf) for other varieties of syntactic cleavage,

Comment: Why would anybody do this to a poor sentence? :(

Comment: "John did give me a cat" ==> "What John did was give me a cat".

Comment: @F.E. Makes sense, but I was wondering if people simplify "give" into "gave" just like in the case of "suggest he should go => suggest he go => suggest he goes"

Comment: You just did. But it's [ungrammatical](http://www.grammaring.com/pseudo-cleft-sentences). ('In the past simple and present perfect, we can use the following patterns: 

What I did in the end was (to) go home.')

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not, but notice: "John did give me a cat" ==> "What John did ***do*** was give me a cat".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth. Thanks for the link. There's a sentence there, and that's what got me thinking - if I say "What they were doing was arguing about which train to take." why not say "What I did was gave a cat"? I - of course - totally accept FE's explanation, but, well, one can wonder...

Comment: Compare: "John will give me a cat" ==> "[What John will ***do***] is [***give*** me a cat]". -- Notice how the last "give" is "give" and not "gives"; because that last "give" is not tensed (not present-tense nor past-tense). -- In your example "[What John did] was [ ***gave*** me a cat]" uses a past-tense "gave", which seems to make that example ungrammatical.

Comment: @f.e. Didn't see your other comments when I sent you my last, they were hidden. However, I'm kind of annoyed with myself now because I don't like the following data: ***What they HAVE done is (to) OPEN the channels of communication.*** This partially kaiboshes any firm evidence that it is unexpressed ***do*** that's governing GIVE. However, it's certainly the case that ***what he's doing is giving/give* you a cat*** supports the case. But is whatever allows HAVE DONE to exist with a bare infinitive, allowing DID to exist with it too? Can't find decisive evidence:( irritatingly

Comment: I'm not a native speaker of EN, but insted of "What they HAVE done is (to) OPEN the channels of communication" I'd go with "What they HAVE done is OPENING the channels of communication" :) You see, "What they HAVE and what is done is OPENING the channels". Right? :)

Comment: *"What they HAVE done is OPENING the channels of communication"* -- The problem with that version is that the perfect of the Left-Hand-Side (LHS) clashes with the progressive of the Right-Hand-Side (RHS); the non-cleft source seems to be something like: "They ***have opening*** the channels of communication", which is ungrammatical. Compare to the grammatical: "What they ***have done*** is ***[ (to) open / opened ]*** the channels of communication" and "What they ***were doing*** was ***opening*** the channels of communication".

Comment: There's also the acceptable: "What they ***have been doing*** is ***opening*** the channels of communication".

Comment: @F.E. I didn't interpret "opening" as the progressive form of "open" but as a gerund. You see - the "opening" is "done".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*OK, so if no-one wiser than me out there is going to help you, I'm going to give it a go:*

The complement of ***BE*** in the first example uses a so-called infinitival construction headed by ***to***, and ***to*** is always followed by the plain form of the verb. We know therefore that this instance of the verb ***GIVE*** has no tense.

The second example has a plain form, an infinitive, although exactly why this is so is perhaps ambiguous. We can certainly show, however, that ***GIVE*** in the second example is not present tense, because it differs from ***GIVE*** in the following badly formed sentence, in that it has no inflectional third person ***s***:

1. All he did was, gives me a cat *

Your third example, however, differs substantially from the first and second because the complement of the verb ***BE***, namely ***he gave me a cat*** , is a finite clause and has a subject. These two factors are not co-incidental. Firstly, finite clauses in English must have a subject (unless they are imperatives) - and secondly, only finite clauses in English have tense. The word **tense** is used here to mean, very specifically, that the verb in question is inflected for time reference (or for modality, or backshift). Because, in your third example, the subject from the relative clause is resumed, the verb can have a full past tense as in ***gave***.

The very short answer to your question, then, is that your interesting fourth example is not allowable because there can be no past tense verb in the clause unless it has an expressed subject. There is no subject in the complement clause ***gave me a cat*** and so there can be no tense.

*Hope this helps.*

Comment: *"What John did was, gives me a cat"* is undeniably wrong because the tenses don't match. You should be comparing *"what John did, was gave me a cat"* with *"what John does, is gives me a cat"*. I don't think either of these sentences sounds that great. But I think both of them should be considered allowable in informal speech, while *"what John did, was gives me a cat"* is always wrong.

Comment: @PeterShor Comparison point taken, but just trying to show that in Jules' example it's an infinitive. Neither acceptable even in informal speech in my variety of English - although the present-past one does sound the worse of the two!

Comment: For me, if somebody said to me *"what John did, was gave me a cat"*, I probably wouldn't even notice there was anything wrong with it. Whereas if they said was *"what John did, was gives me a cat"*, I would be thinking *why doesn't this person know how to speak English?*

Comment: @PeterShor I suppose the grammaticality is in the ear of the beholder :)